# Using reverse() with BigInteger in java

Tags: java, biginteger

I need to find the next palindrome of the input such that the number is not more than 1000000 DIGITS.
For this i am using BigInteger and I am getting "Time limit exceeded".

What to do now ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;


class Ideone
{
    static boolean palindrome(BigInteger a)
    {
        String b=""+a;
        StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer(b);
        StringBuffer c=s.reverse();
        String d=c.toString();

        return d.equals(b);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t-->0){
            BigInteger k=sc.nextBigInteger();
            try{for(BigInteger i=k.add(BigInteger.ONE);;i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
                if(palindrome(i)){System.out.println(""+i); break;}

            }//for
            }catch(Exception e){}


        }//wh
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Time limit exceeded.

Comment: If this code works you could post it to CodeReview. And i would start with using valueOf to cache at least some values and why you convert them to string?

Comment: Don't use `BigInteger`, use a `char[]` instead to store the digits of the number.

Comment: Trying drawing out these kind of problems on pen and paper.  You'd be surprised what you could learn.

Comment: Your logic seems to be messed up.  If the user enters "1969", you're looking at all numbers from 1 to 1969 to see if they're palindromes, including things like 232.  I don't think that's what you're supposed to accomplish.  I think you're supposed to be looking just at the digits of the input, so that 969 is one of the outputs, not every palindromic number that is less than 1969.  But I don't know--you could have stated the question incorrectly.

Comment: I need a number after the input..like if input is 808 then ouput should be 818..i am getting correct answer for small inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [V-X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2073232/v-x) pointed out, there's no need for the whole incrementing business because we can turn things around: rather than checking which number is a palindrome, we can create palindromes first and test whether they're bigger than our target number.

**Imagine that your number is 123456. What's the smallest palindrome that is bigger than it?**

- Is there a solution in the form 123xyz *(x,y and z denote the missing digits)*? There's only one palindromic number of that form: 123321. But because 123321<123456, that's not our answer.
- So how about 124xyz? Following the same logic we find there's only one such number, 124421, which is greater than 123456.
- Can there be any other palindromes in between? Since there are no numbers between 123999 and 124000, we've proven that there can't be.
- Therefore our answer is 124421.

To sum it up what we did: we took the first half of the number (123456 -> 123), mirrored it (123 -> 123321), found that it's below our target, so we added 1 (123 -> 124) and mirrored it (124 -> 124421), and there's our answer. Had our initial number been something like 123004, we would've accepted 123321 as our answer straight away.

I'll leave it to you to work out what should happen when you've got an odd number of digits and in the case your number is in the form of 9999...9.

By the way, if you're testing for palindromes, there is no need to reverse the number. You can simply check whether the first digit equals the last digit, then compare the second to the second to last and so on. It'll be much, much faster as you only scan the string once.

Comment: Without incrementation how can i get the next number ?

Comment: Imagine that your number is 123456. What's the smallest palindrome that is bigger than it? Is there a solution in the form 123xyz? No, because there's only one palindromic number of that form: 123321, which is <123456. So how about 124xyz? Again, there's only one such number, 124421. Can there be any other palindromes in between? No, we've proven that. Therefore our answer is 124421. To sum it up: take the first half of the number (123456 -> 123), add 1 (123 -> 124) and mirror it (124 -> 124421), and there's your answer. All you need to work out is the case where your number is 999123.

Comment: @biziclop Your comment should be an answer; and your answer should be a comment.

Comment: @DavidWallace You make an awful lot of sense there. :) Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing numbers by BigInteger.ONE? That must be a joke for numbers with 1000000 digits...
Have you thought how long would it take?

Task spoiler (please ignore):

> How about cutting the number to half number of digits and concatenate with this half reversed, and do one change when necessary? Would it be too difficult?

If you know, that the problem is time related, you shoud surround the code with some time measurement and logging. You should log how many digits you have and how much time does it take to verify the palindrome. And you should start with very small numbers first.

Comment: And you solved the entire problem and killed the fun for OP =\ still +1

Answer (score 0):

You should try to minimise your use of `BigInteger` for this, because all the conversions between `String` and `BigInteger` take up unnecessary time.  Just use `next()` instead of `nextInt()` to get each number from the scanner, and keep it as a `String`.  Once you have the number, there are five cases to consider, which you could program in a series of `if` / `else if` blocks.

- **Case 1 - The input in invalid - it doesn't consist entirely of digits.**  It's not clear how you want to handle this, or whether you even want to bother.
- **Case 2 - The input consists entirely of nines.**  If there are `n` nines, then the next palindrome consists of a one, `n-1` zeroes, and another one.  For example, the next palindrome above `9999` is `10001`.
- **Case 3 - The second half of the number, reversed, is less than the first half of the number.**  You can use string comparison for this - there's no need to convert anything to any numeric type.  If there are an odd number of digits (say `2n+1`) then you can round downwards  (to `n`) when figuring out how many digits to examine.  In this case, the next palindrome consists of the the first half of the number, then the middle digit if there is one, then the first half of the number reversed.  For example, if the input is `5678123`, then compare `567` to `321`.  Since `567` is greater, this case applies, and the output should be `5678765`.
- **Case 4 - None of the other cases apply, even number of digits.** Take the first half of the number and add one (and you can use `BigInteger` to do this step if you like).  The output is the result of this, followed by its reversal.  For example, if the input is `123789` then the first half of the number, with one added, is `124` and the output should be `124421`.
- **Case 5 - None of the other cases apply, odd number of digits.** Take the first half of the number; rounding upwards when figuring out how many digits to include.  For example, if the input is `1234789`, then take `1234`.  Now add one, then output the result, followed by the reversal of all but the last digit of the result.  In this example, you'd output `1235` followed by the reversal of `123` - that is, `1235321`.  Just like `case 4`, you can use `BigInteger` for the addition.